# Copyright - Teaching propietary framework for customer who has the licence

Tags: contracts, copyright, licensing

Framework (x) is under propietary licence, it's API and documentation is publicly availbale for anyone. Commercial use without permission is prohibited.

Customer (A)  is licensed to use the framework x and even sells products involving framework x. He is ordering me as a FL to teach one of his own customers (B) about framework x.

I am heavily using the documentation to prepare the seminar. Am I getting legally in trouble? Anyone experience in that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you are working on behalf of customer A, you should be covered by their license to train customer B. If this is prohibited, it is customer A who has breached the licensing agreement.

For the sake of CYA, ensure that all expectations are documented, and flag your licensing concern to company A.